# Retrieve the number and IMEI of the mobile phone

Tags: android

I want to retrieve the own mobile number and the IMEI.

How do I get this information from the Android phone?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
// get IMEI
String imei = tm.getDeviceId();
String phone = tm.getLine1Number();
```

but its not always reliable on for example non phone device.

and you should also **add this following permission** to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Not all devices detect the phone number, at least in my LG optimus black I have to put it in manually (and not a lot of users do this I guess).

Answer (score 2):

`getLine1Number();`

this method returns the phone number string for line 1, 
i.e the **MSISDN** for a **GSM** phone. Return null if it is unavailable.

but what about **CDMA** phone?

> **Note** : this method works only for few cell phone not for all devices

.