# How to get Mobile Model and name when app is launched?

Tags: android

Good Day! I am working on an android app which monitor mobile name and model. I am using TELEPHONY SERVICE but i am in trouble how to write code for get mobile IMEI number.

Comment: duplicated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660938/how-can-i-get-phone-serial-number-imei

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically get the devices IMEI/ESN in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-programmatically-get-the-devices-imei-esn-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 // get IMEI
String imei = tm.getDeviceId();
String phone = tm.getLine1Number();
```

but its not always reliable on for example non phone device. You will also need to add permision "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE".

[TelephonyManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394238/retrieve-the-number-and-imei-of-the-mobile-phone)

[Google Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
String deviceModel = Build.MODEL;
String deviceBrand = Build.BRAND;
TelephonyManager manager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String imei = manager.getDeviceId();
```

Also add that permission to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

If you want to get another info about your phone, you should read the links;

- [android.os.build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)
- [android.telephony](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
  public String getDeviceName() 
   {
    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String model = Build.MODEL;
    if (model.toLowerCase().startsWith(manufacturer.toLowerCase())) {
        return capitalize(model);
    } 
    else {
        return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
    }
}




private String capitalize(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    char first = s.charAt(0);
    if (Character.isUpperCase(first)) 
     {
        return s;
    } else {
        return Character.toUpperCase(first) + s.substring(1);
    }
}
```